# How to have the min, max and latest price with the time it came in one row for each symbol? (postgres)

Tags: sql, postgresql

**The goal**

I would want to get the min price, max price and the latest price along with their time from my table.

**The Problem:**

However I cannot get the most recent min price and max price along with the most recent price.

I am able to only get the max and min price but it is not the most recent max and min price. (eg. I want 6 Nov but it gives me 2 Feb)

I have tried options such as DISTINCT ON and PARTITION BY but still I cant get what I want.

Here is my table:

```
       tradetime        | symbol  |     price      |
 2020-10-28 13:06:48+08 | symbolA | 11353.35000000 | 
 2020-10-28 13:40:13+08 | symbolA | 11600.35000000 | 
 2020-10-28 13:40:25+08 | symbolA | 11600.35000000 | 
 2020-10-28 13:42:44+08 | symbolA | 10000.35000000 |
 2020-10-28 13:42:59+08 | symbolA | 10000.35000000 |
 2020-10-28 14:24:41+08 | symbolA | 11500.85000000 |
 2020-11-02 17:03:12+08 | symbolB |   300.35000000 |
 2020-11-02 17:03:30+08 | symbolB |   300.35000000 |
 2020-11-02 17:03:48+08 | symbolB |   400.35000000 |
 2020-11-02 17:03:58+08 | symbolB |   400.35000000 |
 2020-11-02 17:04:17+08 | symbolB |   350.35000000 |
 2020-11-02 17:05:07+08 | symbolB |   350.35000000 |
```

I want to get a result like:

```
 symbol  |   minpriceTradetime    |  MinimumPrice  |   maxiPriceTradetime   | maxPrice        | LatestPriceTradetime    | LatestPrice                                                     
 symbolA | 2020-10-28 13:42:59+08 | 10000.35000000 | 2020-10-28 13:40:25+08 | 11600.35000000  | 2020-10-28 14:24:41+08  | 11500.85000000                                                
 symbolB | 2020-11-02 17:03:30+08 |   300.35000000 | 2020-11-02 17:03:58+08 | 400.35000000    | 2020-11-02 17:05:07+08  | 350.35000000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite easy with window functions - you just need to set the proper ordering:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT symbol,
FIRST_VALUE(tradetime) OVER(PARTITION BY symbol ORDER BY price,tradetime DESC)      AS minTrade,
FIRST_VALUE(price)     OVER(PARTITION BY symbol ORDER BY price,tradetime DESC)      AS minPrice,
FIRST_VALUE(tradetime) OVER(PARTITION BY symbol ORDER BY price DESC,tradetime DESC) AS maxTrade,
FIRST_VALUE(price)     OVER(PARTITION BY symbol ORDER BY price DESC,tradetime DESC) AS maxPrice,
FIRST_VALUE(tradetime) OVER(PARTITION BY symbol ORDER BY tradetime DESC)            AS lastTrade,
FIRST_VALUE(price)     OVER(PARTITION BY symbol ORDER BY tradetime DESC)            AS lastPrice
FROM myTable
```

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres, you can do this with array functions:

```
select symbol,
       min(price) as min_price,
       (array_agg(tradetime order by price))[1] as min_price_tradetime,
       max(price) as max_price,
       (array_agg(tradetime order by price desc))[1] as max_price_tradetime,
from t
group by symbol;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it did give me a path to think!